# Can't keep lines from crossing in simple graph using Rgraphviz

Tags: r, graph

So just starting with Rgraphviz and for some reason it crossing lines on my really simple graph.

```
A = matrix(c(0,0,0,0,1,
         1,0,0,0,0,
         1,0,0,0,0,
         1,0,0,0,0,
         0,1,1,1,0),
       ncol=5, byrow=TRUE)
rownames(A)=c(1,2,3,4,5)
colnames(A)=c(1,2,3,4,5)

library(Rgraphviz)
am.graph<-new("graphAM", adjMat=A, edgemode="directed")
am.graph
plot(am.graph, attrs = list(node = list(fillcolor = "lightblue"),
                            edge = list(arrowsize=0.5)))
```

[image]

Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`RGraphiviz` offers a number of layout algorithms, see ?GraphvizLayouts. The default, used in your example, is the "dot" algorithm, which gives a hierarchical layout. One of the alternatives, "twopi", takes one of the nodes as a root and arranges the remaining nodes in a series of concentric circles about this root. This second algorithm can be used here to avoid crossed lines in the graph.

By default, "twopi" uses node 1 as the root:

```
plot(am.graph, "twopi", 
     attrs = list(node = list(fillcolor = "lightblue"),
         edge = list(arrowsize=0.5)))
```

[image: 5 node graph produces with "twopi" algorithm]

However, we can change this via the attributes (see ?GraphvizAttributes) to set node 2 as the root:

```
plot(am.graph, "twopi",
 attrs = list(graph = list(root = 2),
     node = list(fillcolor = "lightblue"),
     edge = list(arrowsize=0.5)))
```

which perhaps gives a layout closer to what you would like:

[image]

Comment: Thanks that seems to do about what I want.